# HibernateException: Missing table error for a Join Table using Grails 2.0.2 on MS SQL legacy database

Tags: sql-server, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am trying to get a many-to-many relationship working using Grails 2.0.1 on Windows 7.  I have exhausted both Google, this site, and my Grails books.  Nothing worked.  I am connecting to a MS SQL Server 2005 database that I have READ only privileges on and yes - it is a legacy database.  Everything in the 2 individual tables works fine (views OK & all) but when I try to add the join table code I get an error:

**org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: dbo.IN_USR_DRAWING_PRIV**

The table does indeed exist and I can see it fine using IntelliJ's IDEA 10.5 Data Sources view & the MS SQL Server Management Studio.  The relevant part of the error is this (I can send more ... much more if needed) :

*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: dbo.`IN_USR_DRAWING_PRIV`*

Here are the 2 domain classes :

```
class Drawing {
static hasMany = [appusers:Appuser]
String id
String drawingId  //this is in the join table
String drawingName

static transients = ['name']

void setName(String name) {
    id = name
}

String getName() {
    return id
}

static mapping = {
    table name: "IN_DRAWING", schema: "dbo"
    version false
    id column: 'DRAWING_ID', generator:'identity', insertable:false, updateable:false
    drawingId column: "`DRAWING_ID`",insertable:false, updateable:false  //this is in the join table
    drawingName column: "`DRAWING_NAME`"
    appusers column: '`USR_ID`',
            joinTable: 'IN_USR_DRAWING_PRIV'
}
```

}

```
class Appuser {
static belongsTo = Drawing
static hasMany = [drawings:Drawing]

String id
String usrId  //this is in the join table
String usrName

static transients = ['name']

void setName(String name) {
    id = name
}

String getName() {
    return id
}

static mapping = {
    table name: 'IN_USR', schema: "dbo"
    version false
    id column:'USR_ID', generator:'identity', insertable:false, updateable:false  //this is in the join table
    drawings column: 'DRAWING_ID',
            joinTable: 'IN_USR_DRAWING_PRIV'
    usrName column: "`USR_NAME`"
    }
```

}

And here is the schema for the join table:

```
dbo.IN_USR_DRAWER_PRIV
    USR_ID        (PK, varchar(23), not null)
    DRAWING_ID    (PK, FK, varchar(23), not null)
    PRIV_ID       (PK, int, not null)
```

GRAG reports it has a composite key of all 3 columns, which it does along with a FK on DRAWING_ID.

Solutions that I have tried :

1. This code (which fails with the "Missing Table" exception.
2. Adding a domain controller for the join table - same result.

Any hints/clues/solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using Groovy SQL directly and passing in the T-SQL.